# How to pass parameter to a bcp command in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to send a query result to a file, so tried to use bcp command. But can't pass any parameters to that. It shows error.

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM CG.dbo.cdyy where EndTime between     DATEADD(s,0,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,'+@date+'),0)) and DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,1,'+@date+')+1,0))  " queryout "D:\cdr_cg.txt" -T -c -t,'
```

Comment: In future, post the actual error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your parametrs before a call master..xp_cmdshell

```
DECLARE @date varchar(10) = '20130311',
        @bcp varchar(8000)

SELECT @bcp = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM CG.dbo.cdyy WHERE EndTime between DATEADD(s,0,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,''' + @date + '''),0)) AND DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,1,'''  + @date + ''')+1,0))  " queryout "D:\cdr_cg.txt" -T -c -t,'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcp
```

Comment: but it gives an error. FYI I declared @ date and @ bcp as varchar
"Procedure xp_cmdshell, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter 'command_string' of type 'varchar'."

Comment: This error occurs because you use varchar(max) for declared variables.How you declared varchar for @date and @bcp? Use date varchar(10), bcp varchar(8000) instead of date varchar(max), bcp varchar(max)

Comment: thanks a lot, you saved my day and yes I was making the same mistake you had specified :)